# Installation of `mpi4py` failed because MPI compilers are not found

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to install mpi4py through anaconda, and got this error.

```
  /opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel8-icelake/gcc-8.4.1/anaconda3-2021.05-fmo625scqdt32etnaksoexe3rd6sea7j/bin/mpicc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel8-icelake/gcc-8.4.1/anaconda3-2021.05-fmo625scqdt32etnaksoexe3rd6sea7j/include/python3.8 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  /opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel8-icelake/gcc-8.4.1/anaconda3-2021.05-fmo625scqdt32etnaksoexe3rd6sea7j/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
  Failed to build mpi4py
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

It apparently complains about the nonexistent command `mpicc`. Running `<mpi compiler> --version`, where `mpi compiler` is any of `mpicc`, `mpicxx`, `mpif90`, and `mpifort`, returns

```
/opt/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel8-icelake/gcc-8.4.1/anaconda3-2021.05-fmo625scqdt32etnaksoexe3rd6sea7j/bin/<mpi compiler>: line 285: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
```

Is it an issue with the anaconda installation?

**EDIT**:
I install `mpi4py` using `pip install --user mpi4py` on a computer cluster where I don't have a root privilege. And the `pip` is provided by `anaconda`.

Comment: If you first install `openmpi-devel` from your OS repo (`yum install openmpi-devel`), does the `mpi4py` install proceed normally?

Comment: I am actually working on a computer cluster, so I don't have the luxury of installing just about any package. `openmpi` is an already existing module in my cluster, and it was loaded before I installed `mpi4py`.

Comment: The MPI library provided by anaconda looks busted: the wrappers are here, but they invoke a compiler that is not available `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc`. But it seems you want to use Open MPI that is **not** from `anaconda`, so there is something fishy here.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet So, are you suggesting that I install OpenMPI from Anaconda? But I had seen OpenMPI under anaconda folders being found by a configure script during an installation of a package that requires MPI. I don't specifically tell Anaconda which mpi to use for the installation of `mpi4py` because I assume it would use its own MPI compilers/wrappers.

Comment: Nope. Generally speaking you should use the Open MPI libraries provided by your sysadmin. In this case, you should have `anaconda/pip` use them.

Comment: Then, is there a way to tell `anaconda/pip` to look for OpenMPI outside of its path?

Comment: IIRC you need to have your PATH set correctly (e.g. load the module after entering anaconda) and then `pip install --user ...`. it's been a while though...

Comment: [`mpi4py` install doc with `pip`](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#using-pip) shows that you can assign `MPICC` environment variable to your specific installation path.

Comment: that looks like https://github.com/conda-forge/openmpi-feedstock/issues/34
anyway, you should not install MPI via anaconda so you use the system provided MPI instead. try `conda uninstall openmpi-mpicc` (or `conda uninstall mpich-mpicc`)

Answer (score 0):

Installing one of the MPI distributions from source will do (if you don't have root previlage). These two guides might help: [#1](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix.html#building-mpi), [#2](https://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/hs12/programming_techniques/openmpi.pdf).
I installed `openmpi` and then `mpi4py` like this

```
wget https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v4.0/openmpi-4.0.1.tar.gz
tar -zxf openmpi-X.X.X tar.gz
cd openmpi-4.0.1
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/openmpi
make all
make install
```

Then export the `/path/to/openmpi/` to `~/.bashrc` and compile:

```
echo "export PATH=/path/to/openmpi/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I cloned the mpi4py repo and built it following [this](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html):

```
wget https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py/releases/download/3.1.4/mpi4py-3.1.4.tar.gz
tar -zxf mpi4py-3.1.4.tar.gz
cd mpi4py-3.1.4
python setup.py build
```

If the `mpicc` command doesn't work, then the installed MPI hasn't been added to path. In that case you can also do:

```
python setup.py build --mpicc=/where/you/have/mpicc
```